# I can't find the location of "Configuration"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I'm currently using IntelliJ IDEA version 2023.3.2, and the "Edit Configurations" interface is quite different from previous versions. I can't find the relevant settings. How can I locate the "VM options" input box?[new version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6L3k.png)[old version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nQKM.png)

I tried searching for the relevant options in the settings but I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right place.[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq6NP.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all the options you need using the "modify option" that is sides the Build And Run.

Hope this help!

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. My English is not good, so I didn't realize it. Thank you very much for your clarification.